# Start-Transcript in Powershell does not work after convert the script to .EXE

Tags: powershell, logging

I use `Start-Transcript` to output the log of process. But after I convert my powershell script to .EXE, the output log is empty, It just show this

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20190924101232
Username: \SYSTEM
RunAs User: \SYSTEM
Configuration Name: 
Machine: MININT-C7288U2 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File X:\CUSTOM\\190910.ps1
Process ID: 1208
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.134
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.134
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.134
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
```

Anyone can give advice how to handle it? Thank you

Comment: What are you using to print the output, `Write-Host` or `Write-Output` ?

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanV I use `Write-Output`

Comment: Can you try with `write-host`

Comment: Yes, I try Write-Host, and It works. But Is there any issue if I change Write-Output to Write-Host?

Comment: @SBR.  The use of `Write-Host` is [generally discouraged](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingWriteHost.md), as discussed [here](https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Comment: `Write-Host` is generally not recommended, but its based on scenarios. IMHO, in this case its fine.